# Exact value of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions

Is it true that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac 3 2\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1/2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{k-1}\right)=\frac{(\sqrt2-4) \zeta(3/2)+4 \pi\sqrt 2}{8 \pi}?$$

(this is in regards to the question: [Convergence of a compound sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741096/convergence-of-a-compound-sequence))

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to compute asymptotics for
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k} = \frac{2}{3}\,n^{3/2}+\frac{1}{2} n^{1/2}\color{red}{-\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4\pi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\tag{1}$$
and
$$ T_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{k+\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(S_{2n+1}-\sqrt{2}\,S_n\right)\tag{2} $$
by summation by parts to find the value of the given series through straightforward algebraic manipulations. The relevant part is just the red term in $(1)$, that equals $\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ by [the reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the $\zeta$ function.

Answer (score 1):

Put $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2k}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2k+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2k-2})$$

and $\displaystyle T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{j}$. Using that $\displaystyle T_{2n+2}=\sqrt{2}T_n+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{2j+1}$, you get a formula for $S_n$ using $T_n$ and $T_{2n+2}$. Now using this answer  [Euler-Maclaurin Summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327644/euler-maclaurin-summation/1327831#1327831)  , you get asymptotic formula for $T_n$, and you can finish the job (with some computations..).